# Could not use lazy variable inside NSCoding protocol methods

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nscoding

I ran into an issue where I could not use a lazy variable inside `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

My sample code is

```
class Category: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var categoryID: NSInteger!
    var categoryName: String!
    var categoryLogoURL: String!
    lazy var categoryTags = [String]()
    private override init() {

    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.categoryID = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "categoryID")
        self.categoryName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryName") as! String
        self.categoryLogoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryLogoURL") as! String
        self.categoryTags = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryTags") as! [String]
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.categoryID, forKey: "categoryID")
        aCoder.encode(categoryName, forKey: "categoryName")
        aCoder.encode(categoryLogoURL, forKey: "categoryLogoURL")
        aCoder.encode(categoryTags, forKey: "categoryTags")
    }
}
```

I am getting an error `Use of 'self' in property access 'categoryTags' before super.init initializes self`

Once I remove `lazy` everything works fine. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call Super Init:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    self.categoryID = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "categoryID")
    self.categoryName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryName") as! String
    self.categoryLogoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryLogoURL") as! String
    self.categoryTags = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "categoryTags") as! [String]
}
```

Comment: Its fixed. Could you explain why its needed to use 'super.init()' to be called if lazy variable is using?

Comment: Looking up for it! It was instinctive.

Comment: @Sree You found the reason?

Comment: @Bista not yet found :(